# react native TextInput : how do i make the text color (or style) not change when TextInput is disabled?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

editable={false}
[image: enable={false}]

editable={true}
[image: enable={true}]

when i press the PencilButton, i want my texinput disabled. but when i press, text in textInput fade.

how to i get the original text?
but another way came to my mind. are you recommend this?

```
const [press,setPress] = useState(false) // when i press button: true
<PencilButton onPress={()=>{setPress(!press)}}
<TextArea press={press}/>

const TextArea = ({press}) => {
   if (press) {
      return <Text>value</Text>
   }
   else{
      return <TextInput/>
   }
}
```

this is when i press button, replace TextInput with Text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **editable** prop to handle disable in react native TextInput. It won't change the text color.

```
<TextInput editable={press} />
```

Comment: thx when i set TextInput styles={{...color:'#mycolor',...}}, text color is not changed.